# aspdotnet core with identity logout call from ajax does not log user out

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to use ajax to post from a link to log a user out using the identity pages.

The page model function I'm calling from ajax is in Logout.cshtml.cs (scaffolded and unmodified):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out."); //I see this output
    if (returnUrl != null)
    {
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl); //this line gets executed
    }
    else
    {
        // This needs to be a redirect so that the browser performs a new
        // request and the identity for the user gets updated.
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

I post to this with ajax like so:

```
$('#submitLogout').on("click", function (e) {
        alert("jquery: Clicked Logout!");
        PostLogout();
        alert("out of Ajax and back to link click function.")
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Home","Index")'
});

function PostLogout() {
    alert("Ajax POST executing . . . ");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Identity/Account/Logout",
        data: { returnUrl: '@Url.ActionLink("Index", "Home")'},
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken: $(
                'input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]'
            ).val()
        },
        success: function () {
            alert("success in Ajax");
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I have verified that the page OnPost handler is being called (with a breakpoint and from the logger information in the console), but my user stays logged in.  If I `return false` from the jquery function I end up with the standard logout page and can `click here to logout` successfully (right outcome but have to click two logout links).  My ajax success function never gets called.

my link code looks like this:

```
<a class="nav-item" id="submitLogout" href="/Identity/Account/Logout">Logout</a>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

I can use a form submit button and get the behavior I want, but the button never looks the same as just a link (font size is always a little bit different) thus my current attempt to post from a link.  This is the form submit  button that works:

```
<form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout"
    asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
    <button type="submit" class="nav-item btn-pgdBanner" style="color: var(--color5)">Logout</button>
</form>
```

I'm not sure if I can get this to work the way I want, so will end up using the standard post from an inline form to logout, but wonder if there is something fairly simple that I'm just missing?